# Problems connecting to weblogic 10.3.6 JMS Queue with authentication from MDB in JBoss 5.1.0 GA

Tags: jms, weblogic, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x, jboss-mdb

I'm using sun-jms-adapter.rar. All my configuration works fine before starting to use authentication. I also tried accessing to queue from a standalone application and stateless bean (this is used to send messages to queue), and all works fine.

My actual configuration is:

weblogic-ds.xml

```
    <connection-factories>

    <!-- SUN JMS JCA Resource adapter, use this to get transacted JMS in beans -->
    <no-tx-connection-factory>
        <jndi-name>CFX/ExternalConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
        <xa-transaction />
        <rar-name>sun-jms-adapter.rar</rar-name>
        <connection-definition>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</connection-definition>
        <config-property name="SessionDefaultType" type="java.lang.String">javax.jms.Queue</config-property>
        <config-property name="JmsProviderAdapterJNDI" type="java.lang.String">java:/DefaultJMSProvider</config-property>
        <config-property name="Destination" type="java.lang.String">javax.jms.Destination</config-property>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
        <depends>jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer</depends>
    </no-tx-connection-factory>
</connection-factories>
```

ejb-jar.xml configuration:

```
    <enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>QueueReceiverMDB</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.tests.mdb.QueueReceiverMDB</ejb-class>
        <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>${weblogic.jms.queue.in}</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>ConnectionURL</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>${weblogic.jms.url}</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>UserName</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>${weblogic.jms.username}</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
                <activation-config-property-name>Password</activation-config-property-name>
                <activation-config-property-value>${weblogic.jms.password}</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>
    </message-driven>
</enterprise-beans>
```

and finally my jboss.xml:

```
        <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>QueueReceiverMDB</ejb-name>
        <destination-jndi-name>java:/CFX/ExternalConnectionFactory</destination-jndi-name>
        <local-jndi-name>local/QueueReceiverMDB</local-jndi-name>
        <resource-adapter-name>sun-jms-adapter.rar</resource-adapter-name>
        <configuration-name>JMSJCA Message Driven Bean</configuration-name>
    </message-driven>
```

I'm allways getting this error:

> 16:25:07,126 WARNING [Activation] JMSJCA-E016: [sync-QueueReceiver(jms/TestJMSQueueIn) @ [t3://localhost:7001]]: message delivery initiation failed (attempt #1); will retry in 1 seconds. The error was: Access denied to resource: type=, application=TestJMSModule, destinationType=queue, resource=TestJMSQueueIn, action=receive
>   weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=, application=TestJMSModule, destinationType=queue, resource=TestJMSQueueIn, action=receive
>       at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:110)
>       at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSync(DispatcherAdapter.java:45)
>       at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.consumerCreate(JMSSession.java:2982)
>       at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.setupConsumer(JMSSession.java:2749)
>       at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createConsumer(JMSSession.java:2691)
>       at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.createReceiver(JMSSession.java:2596)
>       at weblogic.jms.client.WLSessionImpl.createReceiver(WLSessionImpl.java:991)
>       at com.stc.jmsjca.core.RAJMSObjectFactory.createMessageConsumer(RAJMSObjectFactory.java:620)
>       at com.stc.jmsjca.core.SyncDelivery$SyncWorker.init(SyncDelivery.java:502)
>       at com.stc.jmsjca.core.SyncDelivery.start(SyncDelivery.java:202)
>       at com.stc.jmsjca.core.Activation.asyncStart(Activation.java:557)
>       at com.stc.jmsjca.core.Activation.access$000(Activation.java:82)
>       at com.stc.jmsjca.core.Activation$1.run(Activation.java:351)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=, application=TestJMSModule, destinationType=queue, resource=TestJMSQueueIn, action=receive
>       at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:110)
>       at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSync(DispatcherAdapter.java:45)
>       at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEConsumer.(FEConsumer.java:296)
>       at weblogic.jms.frontend.FESession$2.run(FESession.java:1076)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
>       at weblogic.jms.frontend.FESession.consumerCreate(FESession.java:1072)
>       at weblogic.jms.frontend.FESession.invoke(FESession.java:3027)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:961)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.invoke(DispatcherServerRef.java:276)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.handleRequest(DispatcherServerRef.java:141)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.access$000(DispatcherServerRef.java:34)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef$2.run(DispatcherServerRef.java:111)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>   Caused by: weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=, application=TestJMSModule, destinationType=queue, resource=TestJMSQueueIn, action=receive
>       at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.handleThrowable(Request.java:87)
>       at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.getResult(Request.java:52)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:1124)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.syncRequest(DispatcherImpl.java:185)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchSync(DispatcherImpl.java:220)
>       at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSync(DispatcherAdapter.java:43)
>       ... 13 more
>   Caused by: weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=, application=TestJMSModule, destinationType=queue, resource=TestJMSQueueIn, action=receive
>       at weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityHelper.checkPermission(JMSSecurityHelper.java:162)
>       at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationSecurityImpl.checkReceivePermission(BEDestinationSecurityImpl.java:87)
>       at weblogic.jms.backend.BEConsumerImpl.init(BEConsumerImpl.java:312)
>       at weblogic.jms.backend.BEConsumerImpl.(BEConsumerImpl.java:268)
>       at weblogic.jms.backend.BEQueueImpl.createConsumer(BEQueueImpl.java:188)
>       at weblogic.jms.backend.BESessionImpl.createBEConsumer(BESessionImpl.java:469)
>       at weblogic.jms.backend.BESessionImpl.createConsumer(BESessionImpl.java:479)
>       at weblogic.jms.backend.BESessionImpl.invoke(BESessionImpl.java:297)
>       at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:961)
>       ... 16 more

Any suggestion is welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, could not be the best one, but it works.

After spent lots of time trying put this working, I checkout the source code of resource adaptor (sun-jms-adapter.rar) from [here](https://java.net/projects/jmsjca/sources/svn/show), and found a possible error. They don't put credentials in initialContext and close context after creating session. So I modify this stepts, by adding "Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL" and "Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS" to context, and leave it open. And this really works. All this in getJndiObject method in RAWLObjectFactory class.

If someone finds another way, and a best way, please share... because they are putting credentials when creating queue Connection, so may be a bug at weblogic source.

I leave the modified code:

```
private Object getJndiObject(UrlParser url, String name, String username, String password) throws JMSException {

    if (sLog.isDebugEnabled()) {
        sLog.debug("Looking up JNDI object " + name);
    }

    if (name == null || name.length() == 0) {
        throw Exc.jmsExc(LOCALE.x("E401: The JNDI name is null"));
    }

    InitialContext ctx = null;
    try {
        if (mSpecialISORBMethod != null) {
            // Works on IS only
            if (mSpecialISORBMethodIsOn != null) {
                Boolean isEnabled = (Boolean) mSpecialISORBMethodIsOn.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
                if (!isEnabled.booleanValue()) {
                    throw Exc.rsrcExc(LOCALE.x("E823: CORBA-SE needs to be enabled on" 
                        + " this server. Please change the value of the <se-orb enabled=\"false\"/>"
                        + " to <se-orb enabled=\"true\"/> in the configuration file of "
                        + " the Integration Server (logicalhost/is/domains/<domain-name>"
                        + "/config/domain.xml) and restart the server."));
                }
            }
            final Properties prop = (Properties) mSpecialISORBMethod.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
            prop.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, JNDI_WEBLOGIC_PROTOCOL_PACKAGES);
            ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
            return ctx.lookup("corbaname:iiop:1.2@" + url.getHost() + ":" + url.getPort()
                + '#' + name); 
        } else {
            // Will be executed on other application servers than the IS

            //add username/password if not null to context
            Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://" + url.getHost() + ":" + url.getPort());
            if (username != null) {
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
                env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            }
            ctx = new InitialContext(env);
            return ctx.lookup(name);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw Exc.jmsExc(LOCALE.x("E821: Could not find JNDI object by name [{0}]: {1}", name, e), e);
    } 
    //leave context open
    /*finally {
        safeClose(ctx);
    }*/
}
```